# Run IG Publisher with unpacked FHIR package

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am using "IG Publisher" to generate static documentation for a custom HL7 FHIR server.

The documentation is generated with:

```
java -jar org.hl7.fhir.igpublisher.jar -spec package.tgz -ig ig.json
```

Where package.tgz is downloaded from https://www.hl7.org/fhir/stu3/package.tgz.

At every run of this, IG Publisher unpacks the package.tgz file which takes 1-2 minutes. Since the files are static, there is no reason for spending time on this unpacking all the time. So I would like to unpack package.tgz once and for all - and then just point IG Publisher to the directory where these unpacked files are found. Something like this:

```
java -jar org.hl7.fhir.igpublisher.jar -spec ./package/ -ig ig.json
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing the spec, allow the NPM package manager to find it and use it.  It'll cache the opened version and will only grab a new version if the spec has changed.  (If you base your IG on the 'current' draft, that'll be often as commits happen regularly, but if you point to R4 or STU3 or DSTU2, changes should be very rare.)  Note that the publisher will still take 10-20 seconds each time you run it to load the specification into memory.

Comment: Hi Lloyd - that sounds promising. I am on STU3. Can you elaborate "allow the NPM package manager to find it and use it" ?

Comment: Ah - I think I get it. You mean that IG Publisher does this when it is run and it stores the package between runs (probably using npm). My challenge was complicated by the fact that IG Publisher is running from a Docker image - so I need to ensure that the unpacked and npm-cached package.tgz is properly contained in that Docker image.

Comment: 6-8 months ago, the IGPublisher started using NPM as a mechanism to manage the distribution of - and gain access to - both the core specifications and all of the various implementation guides that new IGs might depend on.  If you're hitting issues with using Docker, I'd suggest raising an issue on https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/179252-IG-creation.  We might be able to adjust the tool or figure out some other fix.